# Where can I get a list of system styles for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Where can I get a list of system styles for Windows Phone? (Perferably with descriptions on how Microsoft wants us to use them.)

Answer (score 3):

You can see a list of the Theme Resources on this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). The colour information and design location can be found in the [Theme Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402557%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Themeresourcefiles).

> Depending on the accent and background color chosen by the end user,
>   theme resources will display different control colors, brushes, and
>   styles. These differences are specified in the theme resource file,
>   named ThemeResources.xaml. There is a different resource file for each
>   combination of accent and background. For a listing of the various
>   resources affected by themes, see Theme Resources for Windows Phone.
>
> Theme resource files are found in the following paths:
>
> ```
> 64-bit Operating Systems: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Design
>
> 32-bit Operating Systems: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Design
> ```

Design guidelines are now available on [this page](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/design/library).